# I have two windows c++ applications build with visual studio. Now I want to develop the an update app to update these applications

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, updates, msdn

We have two windows c++ applications developed with visual studio.

Now we want to develop an utility to update these applications, following are the requirements: -

1. Whenever user invokes the application, then user could initiate a update app utility using some GUI
   hooks.
2. Another requirement is after every week, a scheduler at system level would check if the updates are
   available then invoke the update app utility.

Now the biggest constraint is c++ applications are installed in c:/programs files folder which is editable by admin users only. If a standard user(non admin) user is trying to use the application and initiate the update app utility then update utility would run in standard user context (non admin context which might not be able to edit anything at location c:/program files.

Update utility should be so generic that it could update more than one applications.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is your question about obtaining administrator rights? If not, please elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Too complex. The weekly scheduler should *be* the application update utility, running as a background service. The GUI hook should just wake up the service from its week-long sleep.